# Assign variable to be used in filename

Tags: r, loops, assign

I'm trying to build a program with macroeconomic data which I can run over different countries by changing just one line of code.

I want to assign something like:

```
countrycode <- "UK"
```

My data matrix columns are labelled GDP_UK, GDP_FR, GDP_DE, ..., FDI_UK, FDI_FR, FDI_DE..., UN_UK, UN_Fr,... etc. I would like to assign something like:

```
gdp <- ts(Data[,c("GDP_UK")], frequency=4, start=c(1971,1), end=c(2013,4))
```

but instead of using "GDP_UK", I'd like to use "GDP_*countrycode*". In Eviews, this would be a 'for i=... do something' loop. I've noticed that loops are not very popular here but I don't see what else could work. The composition of my data matrix can change so I don't want to create a vector with all the country codes (would be messy as soon as I change the data matrix). I would instead like to change the country code eg from UK to FR and have my program run for France instead of the UK. How do I get the variable 'countrycode' into my ts command?

Comment: `country <- paste("GDP", countrycode, sep="_"); gdp <- ts(Data[ ,country], ...`?

Comment: Change your matrix to a `list` with each element's name being a country code? Then you can add new country codes (and the associated data) to your list without affecting the existing data, and you can select the desired item by doing `ts(Data$pick_a_code,...)`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: This might be problematic, because I have sevaral variables per country. So I cant just assign the country code. They are named Variable_countrycode at the moment.

Roland: Thanks, that works! But its a bit messy, I have to create a 'country' variable for every variable in my dataset and then drop them again. 3 lines of code for every variable. But it does the job! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roland pointed out you can build the string to identify the column names with the `paste` command

```
varname <- "GDP"
countrycode <- "UK"
columnname <- paste(varname, countrycode, sep="_");
```

And then you can extract it like you with with a regular string

```
gdp <- ts(Data[,columnname], frequency=4, start=c(1971,1), end=c(2013,4))
```

Comment: perfect. How can I use this to create a newly named element with this variable? such as: data_"countrycode" <- c(1,2) ?

Comment: @user3468631 Data[, paste("data", countrycode, sep="_")] <- c(1,2)

Comment: that seems to try to work with the Data Matrix. I want to create a new object (the vector c(1,2) for example). Call it Test for simplicity?

Comment: @user3468631 Rather than asking new questions in comments, if you need additional help, please post a new question so others can help.